# Bypassing phone to SIM card connection in android OS

Tags: android, sim-card

In a android device:
Is it possible to change the defenition at the OS to access the SIM card in order to get the needed information for the authentication process to the GSM network.
where in the OS is this defenition made?
can it be changed to acess a different source containing a SIM CARD application and info?

Thanks

Comment: This cannot be done from application space

Comment: Yes, I know.
 Is there other way? If yes, I would appreciate information about it.